# HDFS high throughput is just because of it's block size?

Tags: linux, hadoop, block, hdfs, throughput

I read that one of HDFS core features is high throughput. I also read that it is because of it's block size and lower seek times . I did a calculation to prove myself that. lets say I have a 10GB file in my Linux filesystem and same file in HDFS. Let the seek time be 10ms and transfer rate be 100MB/s. I am only changing the block size from 512B to 128MB.So if I want to read the data from Linux filesystem.

```
total read time = total transfer time + total seek time 
total transfer time = number of blocks* ( size of the block / transfer rate )
total seek time = number of block* 10ms
```

so therefore

for normal Linux file system

```
number of blocks= 10*1024*1024*1024/512 = 21 million blocks(approximately)
transfer time = 512/(100*1024*1024/1000) = 0.00488ms

total read time = 21000000(0.00488+10) = 58.36 hours
```

for HDFS

```
number of blocks = (10*1024)/128 = 80
transfer time = 128/(100/1000) = 1280ms

total read time = 80* (1280+10) = 103 seconds
```

did I get my calculations wrong? and also please tell me is this the reason why HDFS has high throughput ? and why it has low latency?
thank you I would I appreciate some clarification.

Comment: What cluster did you use for your HDFS test? The high throughput comes primarily from reading multiple disks in parallel.

Comment: single node cluster.